# Inserting Separator in ListView using Array Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Scenario : I have n number of tabs each tab is having its own listview. I am using a Array adapter to generate a listview. The array which is passed to arrayadaper is having array of objects. Each object has  and . Now based on the menu type, if the menu type is "menugroup" i need to draw using a different layout and set the background to RED colour.

Question is simple.. Whenever I scroll down / up the property of menugroup row in listview is getting passed to other rows in listview. In otherwords scrolling disturbs the seperator.

Following is the code of Adapter. Could you please guide me to the point where it needs correction ? Thanks in Advance.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Menu> {
private ArrayList<Menu> menuItemList; 
Context context;
LayoutInflater vi;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context ,ArrayList<Menu> menu) {    
        super(context, 0, menu );    
        this.menuItemList = new ArrayList<Menu>();    
        this.menuItemList.addAll(menu); 
        this.context =context;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    }    

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView menuItem;   
        TextView menuGroup;  
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {      
        ViewHolder holder;    
        int type =0;
        String menuType = menuItemList.get(position).getMenuType();
        if (menuType.equals("menugroup"))
            type=1;
        if (menuType.equals("menuitem"))
            type=2;

        if (convertView == null) { 
            holder = new ViewHolder();  
            switch (type) {
                case 1:
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.group,  null); 
                holder.menuItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
                break;              

                case 2:
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.item,  null); 
                holder.menuItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem); 
                break; 
            }  
            convertView.setTag(holder); 
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }    

    switch (type) {
    case 1:         
    holder.menuItem.setText(menuItemList.get(position).getItemName()) ; 
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
    break;              
    case 2:
          holder.menuItem.setText(menuItemList.get(position).getItemName()) ;  
    break; 
        }
        return convertView; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now based on the menu type, if the menu type is "menugroup" i need to draw using a different layout and set the background to RED colour.

You need to override `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` to display more than one type of layout, otherwise you fight the Adapter's recycler...

---

It looks as though you have done most of the work, but let's alter some of your code:

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (menuItemList.get(position).getMenuType().equals("menugroup")) 
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Then use `getView()` like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {      
    ViewHolder holder;    
    if (convertView == null) { 
        holder = new ViewHolder();  
        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case 0:
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.group,  null); 
            holder.menuItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvGroup);
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
            break;              
        case 1:
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.item,  null); 
            holder.menuItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem); 
            break; 
        }  
        convertView.setTag(holder); 
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }    

    holder.menuItem.setText(menuItemList.get(position).getItemName()); 

    return convertView; 
}
```

---

> how can i ignore clicks on the menuGroups row?

In a very similar way, you need to override two more methods `areAllItemsEnabled()` and `isEnabled(int)`. Since the enabled items are simply a particular item type from above the code looks also identical.

```
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return menuItemList.get(position).getMenuType().equals("menugroup"); 
}
```

Comment: Sam, one more Question.. how can i ignore clicks on the menuGroups row.. any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add seprator by binding the custom xml file like this..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrblog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >






    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.18" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnrdivider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.20"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear123"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/seprater_line" >

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in your java file write this code..

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.customer_list);

        btnAddCustomer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddCustomer);
        lst_customer_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        list=new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Mehul");
        list.add("Sanket");
        list.add("Nitin");
        list.add("Angel");
        list.add("Kirti");
        list.add("Kirit");
        list.add("Gangeshwar");
        list.add("Bhavesh");

        lst_customer_list.setAdapter(new Listadapter(getApplicationContext(), R.id.listView1, list));


    }

    public class Listadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {   
        ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public Listadapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<String> list) 
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
            this.mList = list;

        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {

            View v = convertView;

            if(v==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v=li.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);

            }

            TextView Title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
            final RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.main);


            String listitem=mList.get(position);

            Title.setText(listitem);


            content.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) 
                {

                }
            });

            return v;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mehul.. I have used getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount and solved it.. Thanks again